# Why do I get a syntax error when I try to use the += operator in a return statement?

Tags: python, syntax-error, operators, addition

I was trying to write something like:-

```
x,y = 5,3
return x+=y
```

I get a syntax error when I do this. What is the underlying problem or mechanics that this syntax error is trying to prevent?

Comment: It's treated as a single statement so you can't use return with it.

Comment: Yes it does thank you